# Access a menu with special code in Samsung in Android

Tags: android

If you use samsung, you can access a special menu with *#*#197328640#*#* code. this code gives some information about phone.. I need some network parameters from these information. For example, sim id, gsm operator info, bandwidth etc.  This is special for samsung or some model of samsung (samsung galaxy s i9000 or sII etc)

You can access this menu nopermission.. I mean, you dont need to be a root user. It calls as "Service Mode"
here is also picture of this menu

[image]

is there any way to access this menu with programmatically.. ? Because I really need these information for a project. maybe I will need some special api from samsung or what...?